# How can I make an Amazon Associates book recommendation based on a set of words?

Tags: cpu-word, recommendation-engine, amazon-advertising-api

I have a website which has headlines on a broad set of topics from architecture to gadgets to oceans to robots. I would like to put an Amazon book recommendation on each page, based on a set of words associated with the current topic.

So, for instance, the oceans page might have word [shark, marine, coral, ocean...]. I want a widget that will recommend one or more books based on that set of words.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at the ItemSearch operation, available through Amazon's Product Advertising API. To get books about sharks, the request would look like:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemSearch&
Keywords=Shark&
SearchIndex=Books
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

This would return an XML response containing a list of books related to your keyword(s):

```
<TotalResults>200</TotalResults>
<TotalPages>20</TotalPages>
<Item>
    <ASIN>0691120722</ASIN>
    <ItemAttributes>
         <Title>Sharks of the World</Title>
         ...
    </ItemAttributes>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ASIN>1604330074</ASIN>
    <ItemAttributes>
        <Title>The Shark Handbook</Title>
        ...
    </ItemAttributes>
</Item>
```

you should then have no problem parsing that response and creating links for your page.